# Can you get an object in a node group before its modifiers are applied?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's say I have a mesh named "Suzanne" and I add a *Subdivision* modifier to it.

And I have another mesh that has a *Geometry Nodes* tree. Here I want to use the mesh "Suzanne", but in the state it was in before the *Subdivision* modifier was applied.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, unfortunately not possible. But you could integrate *Suzanne* without subdivision modifier in two node trees with `Object Info` and use `Subdivision Surface` in *Geometry Nodes* instead.

Comment: Depending on your particular need, you could save needed data as an attribute, and even recreate the mesh.

Comment: You could't bring Unsubdivided Suzanne as an instance into  Mesh 2's  tree, do what you want with her, and subdivide her _inside_ that the tree for output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we approach this problem as asked in the title, no, objects are stored by Blender only in their final form.  Once it has been evaluated, there is no longer any record of an object between two modifiers, there is only the final output; and an object is generally evaluated only once per frame, so we don't have any situations where we evaluate an object part way, then evaluate some other object, then return to our first object to evaluate it.  Doing things this way can be important for reasons of performance and memory use.

However, the underlying problem is that you want to refer to an unsubdivided Suzanne with geometry nodes, and you want to render a subdivided Suzanne, not an unsubdivided Suzanne.  This problem is totally solvable.  It just requires using an additional object, or rendering Suzanne in a different object.

We can make a linked duplicate of Suzanne, parent it to her, give it a subdivision modifier, and disable rendering on the original.  Any changes we make to the original will be reflected in our new linked, parented duplicate, while our geometry nodes modifier will still refer to our original, unsubdivided Suzanne.  But modifiers that we add to either the original or duplicate will be unique to that particular copy of her.

Or instead of rendering a duplicate of Suzanne, we can disable rendering on her, and then use a geometry nodes modifier to instance her on any mesh object, after which we can subdivide that geometry, either in a further subdivision modifier, or right there in the instancing geometry nodes modifier.  Again, any changes we make to the original Suzanne will be reflected in our instance.  In this case, that includes modifiers on the original.  But modifiers on the instancing object will not be reflected back onto the original.

If we really don't want to make any new objects, we can even instance her onto an existing object-- let's say, onto the object referring to her in GN:

[image]

So here, I have an unsubdivided Suzanne in the scene, and my plane is shrinking to that unsubdivided Suzanne, then instancing and subdividing her geometry.  We could just as easily subdivide outside the GN, if we were happy with also subdividing our plane.

Sometimes people think that doing things like using duplicate objects and non-rendering objects is somehow a trick that you shouldn't have to use, but it's necessary in a wide variety of situations.  It can split a modifier stack, but it can also be essential for working around dependency loops.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using more than one object you could also use multiple node trees to save geometry like so:

[image]